# Gender independent term for address a superior or higher up

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, gender-neutral

For times when I am unaware of whether my superior is male or female, it would be very convenient to have a gender neutral term for addressing them.

For example, in the sentence:

> Hello _____ , I have completed the report you had given to me this morning.

After thinking for some time, and doing some research on this site as well as online, I couldn't find any helpful resources. If someone could share their opinion on this matter, I would be very grateful.

Comment: This is quite possibly a lexical gap, B.M. The usual workaround in impersonal communications is of course << Dear Sir / Madam. >>.

Comment: Workplaces are increasingly moving to an egalitarian style (if not egalitarian salaries or conditions), where superiors and inferiors are addressed by their first name, or by terms such as "colleague" or "associate". (If you actually want a term meaning a senior, there's a wide range depending on country, formality, industry etc: boss, guv'nor/guv, chief, gaffer, your majesty; and some formal job titles will also work as forms of address. Where are you, doing what?)

Comment: It is odd that you are trying to combine a formal way of addressing a superior with *hello* (a relatively informal greeting).

Comment: Is this in speech, or writing?

Comment: @jsw29 Would there be any other alternatives? Perhaps "Greetings" or "Dear"? Both seem a bit to endearing in my opinion, compared to a basic "Hello".

Comment: @TinfoilHat Direct speech ie. a text message.

Comment: @BongoMan, *Dear ___* is the most standard salutation in a letter in English; nobody takes it literally.

Comment: For times when you are unaware of how your superior prefers to be addressed, would it not behoove you to find out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing would be the meaning of the word ***senior***:

> high or higher in rank ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/senior))

But the English do not address their seniors with such appellatives. In very formal contexts this is resolved by the expression

> To Whom It May Concern

but this formula is considered by some obsolete and not appropriate for emails.

Instead, you could just use their name or the name of their function, if you know it:

> Hello, Mr/Mrs Manager/Director etc.

As [Scribbr.com](https://www.scribbr.co.uk/strong-communication/to-whom-it-may-concern-alternatives/) explains

> Even if you don’t know the name of the person you’re writing to, it’s usually best to either find out or use a job title or department name to make your salutation more personal.
>
> Examples: Dear Operations Team, … 
> Dear Head of Marketing, …
> Dear Ms Birbal, …

Comment: The formulation 'To Whom It May Concern' is usually used when one does not know at the time of writing who will be reading the letter (while it seems that in the OP's case there is one definite recipient, it's just that the OP does not know the recipient's name). Also, there is something odd about combining Mr/Mrs with a title, rather than a name, and combining *hello* (a relatively informal greeting) with a formal form of address.

Comment: Did you miss the part about “gender independent” *Mr*? *Ms*? *Mrs* (!) (really?)

Comment: Did you miss the slash between them?

Comment: I believe you are suggesting a literal salutation of e.g. "Hello, Mr/Mrs Manager," where you intend *Mr/Mrs* to cover, uh, either a presumed male or a presumed married female.